# Prove $\sum_{d\le x} \sum_{q\le x/d} \dfrac{1}{q^{\beta}} = \sum_{d\le x} \dfrac{1}{d^{\beta}} \sum_{q\le x/d} 1$?

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-number-theory, proof-explanation

The below texts are from the book Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol:

[image]

Trying to calculate $\sum_{n\le x} \sigma_{\alpha} (n)$ for negative $\alpha$ I followed the advice of the book, i.e. " ... we write $\alpha = - \beta$, where $\beta>0$" and the recipe in Theorem 3.5. above. So, $$\sum_{n\le x} \sigma_{-\beta} (n) = \sum_{n\le x} \sum_{q|n} \dfrac{1}{q^{\beta}} = \sum_{d\le x} \sum_{q\le x/d} \dfrac{1}{q^{\beta}} = \sum_{d\le x} \left\{\frac{1}{1-\beta} (\frac{x}{d})^{1-\beta} + \zeta (\beta) + O (x^{-\beta})\right\} = \dfrac{x^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta} \sum_{d\le x} \dfrac{1}{d^{1-\beta}} +\dfrac{x}{2} \zeta(\beta)+ O(1) + O\Big(\dfrac{x^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta}+\zeta(\beta)+x^{-\beta}\Big). $$

I am disappointed to go further for two reasons: **a.** $\sum_{d\le x} \dfrac{1}{d^{1-\beta}}$ has not a single formula for any $\beta>0$ and **b.** the book has solved it differently and I don't know the equivalence of the different methods, i.e.

[image]

How $\sum_{d\le x} \sum_{q\le x/d} \dfrac{1}{q^{\beta}} = \sum_{d\le x} \dfrac{1}{d^{\beta}} \sum_{q\le x/d} 1$? (especially they probably are not equal as they result in different answers.)

Comment: @JohnM, $∑_{n≤x}σ_{−β}(n)=∑_{d≤x}∑_{q≤x/d}1/{q^β}$ by definition as the method appeared in Theorem 3.5. ; in Theorem 3.6. it is written $∑_{n≤x}σ_{−β}(n)=∑_{d≤x}1/{d^β}∑_{q≤x/d}1$ ; so Apostol has considered $∑_{n≤x}∑_{q≤x/d}1/{q^β}=∑_{d≤x}1/{d^β}∑_{q≤x/d}1$ but I don't know a proof of $∑_{n≤x}∑_{q≤x/d}1/{q^β}=∑_{d≤x}1/{d^β}∑_{q≤x/d}1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the step you are having trouble with is this one?
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d^\beta}= \sum_{d \leq x} \frac{1}{d^\beta} \sum_{q \leq x/d} 1$$

Perhaps this makes it more clear?
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{d|n} \frac{1}{d^\beta} = \sum_{qd \leq x}  \frac{1}{d^\beta} = \sum_{d \leq x} \sum_{q \leq x/d} \frac{1}{d^\beta}  = \sum_{d \leq x} \frac{1}{d^\beta} \sum_{q \leq x/d} 1$$

Here you should regard the sum $\sum_{qd \leq x}$ to mean the sum over all pairs of positive integers $(q,d)$ such that $qd \leq x$.

Comment: If so, why not $\sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{d|n} d^\alpha= \sum_{d \leq x} d^\alpha \sum_{q \leq x/d} 1$ in the proof of theorem **3.5.**, which actually results in different conclusion!

Comment: I want to treat bot cases of $\alpha>0$ and $\alpha<0$ in $\sigma_{\alpha}$ by same method. I don't know if I am clear with my question?

Comment: Answer to your 1st comment:  It doesn't result in a different conclusion.   It results is a less precise estimate.

Comment: Answer to your 2nd comment:  If you try to treat both cases together, you'll get basically a trivial estimate.  I know that you attempted to treat $\alpha < 0$ in a "unified way" but I think you would agree that it didn't come out too well?  And therefore there is a reason to treat $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha < 0$ separately?